# Why is the transformation matrix not the identity matrix?

Tags: processing

Trying to grok the transformation matrices in Processing Python Mode.

Dirt simple program that never transforms anything

```
def setup():
    print("original matrix ".format())
    printMatrix()
    size(200, 200, P3D)

    print("after-size matrix ".format())
    printMatrix()

    line(10,30,90,50)

    resetMatrix()
    print("after resetMatrix()".format())
    printMatrix()
```

I was expecting the same output throughout the script:

```
1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  1.0000
```

But instead, the initial transformation matrix isn't an identity matrix -- it has some extra small values in the fourth column. Until I `resetMatrix()` I don't get the identity matrix that I expected.

```
original matrix 
 001.0000  000.0000  000.0000 -100.0000
 000.0000  001.0000  000.0000 -100.0000
 000.0000  000.0000  001.0000 -173.2051
 000.0000  000.0000  000.0000  001.0000

after-size matrix 
 001.0000  000.0000  000.0000 -100.0000
 000.0000  001.0000  000.0000 -100.0000
 000.0000  000.0000  001.0000 -173.2051
 000.0000  000.0000  000.0000  001.0000

after resetMatrix()
 1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  1.0000
```